Calculating excitonic optical properties with BSE level in VASP
I have been working on 2D material systems and their heterostructures. While calculating BSE excitonic optical properties in VASP, I encountered that the 2D material property is well matched with existing literature. However, while calculating for the vdW heterostructures, the optical properties data show the transmission is all 1 and other values are zero (dielectric functions, absorbance, and others). Also, the vasprun.xml file shows zero value in optical transition. What could be the possible reason for that? Do I need to change any process in VASP for calculating the heterostructure? Please suggest.
I have got the QP energies as bellow:
QP shifts <psi_nk| G(iteration)W_0 |psi_nk>: iteration 1
 for sc-GW calculations column KS-energies equals QP-energies in previous step
 and V_xc(KS)=  KS-energies - (<T + V_ion + V_H > + <T+V_H+V_ion>^1  + <V_x>^1)


 k-point   1 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  KS-energies  QP-energies   sigma(KS)   V_xc(KS)     V^pw_x(r,r')   Z            occupation Imag(sigma)

      1     -62.8363     -65.2242     -27.0299     -22.8607     -38.6210       0.5728       2.0000       1.8799
      2     -37.0378     -38.0953     -23.7962     -22.0873     -32.4098       0.6188       2.0000       1.3720
      3     -36.8254     -37.7533     -23.7562     -22.2636     -32.4047       0.6217       2.0000       1.2829
      4     -36.8254     -37.7533     -23.7562     -22.2636     -32.4047       0.6217       2.0000       1.2829
      5     -16.4670     -17.7385     -13.5822     -11.9121     -19.5849       0.7613       2.0000       2.1266
      6     -15.6562     -16.3879     -13.5268     -12.5216     -19.9985       0.7280       2.0000       2.1676
      7     -14.6190     -15.3365     -13.5135     -12.5264     -19.4682       0.7269       2.0000       1.8251
      8      -7.5844      -8.2602     -12.2364     -11.3903     -15.6500       0.7987       2.0000       0.7739

 k-point   2 :       0.2000   -0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  KS-energies  QP-energies   sigma(KS)   V_xc(KS)     V^pw_x(r,r')   Z            occupation Imag(sigma)

      1     -62.8288     -65.2243     -27.0334     -22.8670     -38.6189       0.5750       2.0000       1.8787
      2     -37.0209     -38.0689     -23.7988     -22.1081     -32.4182       0.6198       2.0000       1.3521
      3     -36.9096     -37.8571     -23.7110     -22.1775     -32.4160       0.6179       2.0000       1.3292
      4     -36.8449     -37.7752     -23.7444     -22.2454     -32.4114       0.6206       2.0000       1.2895
      5     -15.8923     -17.1215     -13.5842     -11.9698     -19.3782       0.7614       2.0000       1.9473
      6     -15.1227     -15.8192     -13.9738     -12.9963     -20.4355       0.7125       2.0000       2.0006
      7     -14.2436     -14.9473     -13.2395     -12.2898     -18.9058       0.7410       2.0000       1.6993
      8      -7.0102      -7.6028     -12.4362     -11.6909     -15.6074       0.7952       2.0000       0.6547

 k-point   3 :       0.4000   -0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  KS-energies  QP-energies   sigma(KS)   V_xc(KS)     V^pw_x(r,r')   Z            occupation Imag(sigma)

      1     -62.8168     -65.2231     -27.0387     -22.8770     -38.6154       0.5782       2.0000       1.8769
      2     -37.0435     -38.0218     -23.6389     -22.0440     -32.4407       0.6134       2.0000       1.4071
      3     -36.9933     -38.0239     -23.8017     -22.1419     -32.4220       0.6210       2.0000       1.3158
      4     -36.8763     -37.8098     -23.7246     -22.2162     -32.4226       0.6189       2.0000       1.3004
      5     -14.3883     -15.5066     -13.6583     -12.1876     -18.8463       0.7604       2.0000       1.5329
      6     -14.2828     -14.9110     -14.9380     -14.0302     -21.4574       0.6921       2.0000       1.7817
      7     -13.0774     -13.7090     -12.7315     -11.9068     -17.6882       0.7659       2.0000       1.3788
      8     -10.0008     -11.0448     -13.3380     -12.0196     -17.0548       0.7919       2.0000       0.8065

 k-point   4 :       0.2000    0.2000    0.0000
  band No.  KS-energies  QP-energies   sigma(KS)   V_xc(KS)     V^pw_x(r,r')   Z            occupation Imag(sigma)

      1     -62.8191     -65.2176     -27.0379     -22.8751     -38.6162       0.5762       2.0000       1.8771
      2     -36.9993     -38.0186     -23.7720     -22.1251     -32.4256       0.6189       2.0000       1.3420
      3     -36.9959     -37.9767     -23.6933     -22.1010     -32.4282       0.6159       2.0000       1.3599
      4     -36.8922     -37.8292     -23.7160     -22.1990     -32.4217       0.6177       2.0000       1.3101
      5     -14.8197     -15.9825     -13.6225     -12.1025     -18.9895       0.7650       2.0000       1.6477
      6     -14.4356     -15.0793     -14.7893     -13.8613     -21.3122       0.6936       2.0000       1.8217
      7     -13.4211     -14.0841     -12.7561     -11.8835     -17.8605       0.7598       2.0000       1.4611
      8      -8.7007      -9.6114     -13.4932     -12.3510     -16.7722       0.7973       2.0000       0.6236

 k-point   5 :       0.4000    0.2000    0.0000
  band No.  KS-energies  QP-energies   sigma(KS)   V_xc(KS)     V^pw_x(r,r')   Z            occupation Imag(sigma)

      1     -62.8131     -65.2275     -27.0407     -22.8801     -38.6147       0.5803       2.0000       1.8762
      2     -37.0386     -38.0163     -23.6419     -22.0501     -32.4351       0.6142       2.0000       1.4009
      3     -36.9848     -38.0120     -23.8029     -22.1524     -32.4247       0.6224       2.0000       1.3056
      4     -36.9332     -37.8765     -23.6914     -22.1585     -32.4328       0.6154       2.0000       1.3308
      5     -14.0571     -14.6685     -15.1023     -14.2224     -21.5755       0.6949       2.0000       1.7189
      6     -13.6048     -14.6591     -13.7255     -12.3556     -18.5442       0.7697       2.0000       1.3413
      7     -12.4684     -13.0429     -12.8139     -12.0695     -17.5470       0.7717       2.0000       1.2372
      8     -10.4955     -11.6021     -13.4402     -12.0323     -17.4385       0.7861       2.0000       0.8922

and the optical properties are:
The optical spectra including excitonic effects are calculated on a grid of 1000 energy points up to 73.1454 eV.

Wavelength (nm)  n_x        k_x        a_x        R_x        T_x        A_x        E_x
        100    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        105    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        110    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        115    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        120    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        125    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        130    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        135    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        140    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        145    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        150    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        155    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        160    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        165    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        170    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        175    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        180    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        185    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        190    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        195    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        200    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        205    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        210    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        215    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        220    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        225    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        230    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        235    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        240    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        245    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        250    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        255    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        260    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        265    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        270    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        275    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        280    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        285    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        290    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        295    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        300    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        305    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        310    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        315    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        320    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        325    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        330    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        335    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        340    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        345    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        350    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        355    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        360    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        365    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        370    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        375    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        380    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        385    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        390    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        395    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        400    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        405    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        410    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        415    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        420    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        425    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        430    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        435    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        440    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        445    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        450    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        455    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        460    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        465    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        470    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        475    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        480    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        485    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        490    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        495    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        500    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        505    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        510    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        515    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        520    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        525    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        530    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        535    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        540    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        545    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        550    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        555    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        560    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        565    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        570    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        575    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        580    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        585    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        590    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        595    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        600    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        605    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        610    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        615    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        620    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        625    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        630    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        635    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        640    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        645    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        650    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        655    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        660    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        665    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        670    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        675    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        680    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        685    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        690    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        695    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        700    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        705    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        710    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        715    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        720    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        725    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        730    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        735    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        740    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        745    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        750    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        755    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        760    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        765    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        770    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        775    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
        780    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000

```

